# What is the difference of using "Threadstart" and without using "Threadstart"

Tags: c#

For thread initialization what is the difference of using "Threadstart" and without using "Threadstart".

```
// 1. 
Thread worker = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoTimeConsumingWork));
worker.Start(); 

// 2. 
Thread worker = new Thread(DoTimeConsumingWork); 
worker.Start();
```

Both are working. 
What is the difference between two.

Regards 
krrish

Comment: I think this is due to the second syntax being added in a post-1.0 version of C#.  I know a lot of syntax regarding delegates got simpler.

Comment: Yes, in .NET 1.0 and 1.1 (I think) the delegate constructor was required; as of 2.0 it is now implicit. Barring some very odd edge-cases, the two behave exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference. The compiler will change your function reference into a delegate at compile time.

IL code of a direct reference:

```
public delegate void Test();
// ...
Test test = TestMethod;

IL_0002: ldftn void testcs.Program::TestMethod()
IL_0008: newobj instance void testcs.Program/Test::.ctor(object, native int)
```

And the exact same IL code appears when it's constructed like:

```
Test test = new Test(TestMethod);

IL_0002: ldftn void testcs.Program::TestMethod()
IL_0008: newobj instance void testcs.Program/Test::.ctor(object, native int)
```

To add on this:
It's more of a personal preference which one you do, but in some cases it might help readability to actually declare the delegate.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real difference. In the latter, the compiler is converting your method group into a `ThreadStart` delegate for you.

Comment: Exactly. And if you're using VB, AddressOf does the same thing in the Thread constructor.

Answer (score 1):

From [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> Visual Basic and C# users can omit
>   the ThreadStart or [ParameterizedThreadStart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart(v=vs.110).aspx) delegate
>   constructor when creating a thread. In Visual Basic, use
>   theAddressOf operator when passing your method to
>   the [Thread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.thread(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor;
>   for example, `Dim t As New Thread(AddressOf ThreadProc)`. In C#, simply
>   specify the name of the thread procedure. The compiler selects the
>   correct delegate constructor.